# TextToSpeech Quality

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-2.2-froyo

I just tested the TTS feature and I'm really disappointed. While the text is mostly recognizable the quality of the sound is horrible.

There is too much noise and it sounds as if there is a lot of clipping as well. I know that TTS can never be as good as a pre-recorded sound file, but I think I'd be satisfied if at least the clipping could be fixed.

I'd try `KEY_PARAM_VOLUME` but it's only supported since API 11 (I use 8), so I'm not sure if that would fix the clipping issue.

Also I'm pretty sure that if I'm streaming the sound to a file the clipping gets stored as well, so no gain from doing that and then using `SoundPool`to play at a lower volume.

Are there any other ways to improve TTS quality?

Comment: What language and locale are you using? I want my speech in English and if I use UK locale it is much better than the US locale. I'm in the UK but I don't see why that would make any difference. (It's not the American accent that influences my assertion by the way, it's purely on grounds of clarity)

Comment: I tried US, UK, German, but the clipping is clearly audible on all of them. Also the static noise is too loud in my opinion and it takes 1-2s after the text to shut down.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest then. I do know that the speech for all languages and locales sounds a lot worse on the emulator than on my actual phone, although that might be because I have a mediocre PC and quite a good phone.

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing on my device, so I'd be glad if my speaker is broken or something, but sadly the prerecorded files sound pretty good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

You shouldn't hear clipping. Did you use the setPitch() method? That sometimes really messes thing up. I suggest NOT calling setPitch().

Also, have faith. The TTS voice quality improved in Android 4.0, perhaps the latest version will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But the clipping is really bad and I tried both, no pitch and lower pitch :( Maybe i record it to a file later just to double-check, but since my prerecorded files (and music for that matter) sounds ok, it has to be something with TTS :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use another TTS provider, which is what many apps do. Have a look in the Market and you'll see lots. Most, unsurprisingly are paid.

Comment: I want to include it in a app, so I'd rather use(/improve) the default. But I guess i need to use prerecorded sounds, if the clipping can't be fixed.